# How can I make a visual header in CSS without PHP?

Tags: html, css

I know that you can make headers/footers (as in the top and bottom of the page) with PHP via include. I've heard that you can do the same with CSS. The idea is to be able to change the header on every page by changing t in one place. How?

Comment: no i don't think you can add html via css

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you mean response headers or the "header" section of a website?  If the latter, can you please describe what you are trying to do?  You cannot create any sort of HTML source with CSS, but you certainly can with do a tremendous amount of styling with CSS.

Comment: Have  you checked this:- http://www.ehow.com/how_8779365_create-effects-under-headers-css.html ?

Comment: Are you talking about http headers? or template headers? or what?

Comment: You can't create content with CSS, but you can render one already there with CSS

Comment: You can use CSS's `content` property to update text, but you can't apply any logic within the CSS stylesheet without also making changes to the DOM (like adding a class to an element).

Comment: Jasper: can you add full-blown html? divs and imgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be done; CSS can not be used to insert elements into a HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

You can import stylesheets with `@import`, but that's only for stylesheets. You can't import HTML into the document with it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an iframe?

```
<iframe src="....../path/filename.html" width="" height="">
```